# viewDidLoad not being called when pushing UIViewController

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, interface-builder, pushviewcontroller

I'm pushing a `UIViewController` like so:

```
UIViewController* individualsController = [[[UIViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"IndividualsController" bundle:nil] autorelease];

[self.navigationController pushViewController:individualsController animated:YES];
```

The NIB itself is loading fine, all the elements load on the screen. BUT none of the view controller's methods are getting called. No viewDidLoad, no viewWillAppear, just a pushed NIB with nothing else.

The view outlet is set up in the NIB; I can't figure out why none of it is getting called!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One possibility is that you are instantiating it as a UIViewController rather than the name of your UIViewController subclass, so it is calling those methods, but on UIViewController, not on your class.  Assuming that the subclass is called `IndividualsController`, try changing the line to

```
IndividualsController* individualsController = [[[IndividualsController alloc] initWithNibName:@"IndividualsController" bundle:nil] autorelease];
```

and see what happens.

Comment: That's not just a possibility, that's what would be happening if @Peter's code really does say `UIViewController` instead of `MyViewController` (or whatever the VC subclass is called).